# How to edit a function to show posts that are expiring in the next days?

Tags: php

The following code shows the posts made the last 30 days. 
Every post I have it has a meta_key named `expiring` with a meta_value of `2011-10-22` for example.

In my case, I want to remove the `post_date` and find what posts are near to be expired. For example, today we have `2011-10-18` and I want to show all the posts that have dates from today (18) until `2011-10-21`. That means 3 days after today.

Tomorrow `2011-10-19` it must show posts that may also expire in `2011-10-22`.

This is how I get the value of the meta_key `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'expiring', true);`

This is the function I tried to edit.

```
<?php
function filter_where($where = '') {
    //posts in the last 30 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');

query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=10&order=DESC');

while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

<li><?php the_title(); ?></li>

<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand the problem properly, but it seems you want to have this in your function:

```
$where .= " AND expire_date < '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 days')) . "'";
```

Sort on expire_date, rather than post date, and take everything where the expire date is not later than 3 days in the future.

Comment: The problem is that there is not `expire_date` but `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'expiring', true);` which I tried.

Comment: This means that the database doesn't list the expiration date, but only the post_date? And to find out what the expiration date is, you need to get it out of the database first, and then ask for the meta_date?

Comment: It seems you then have to get all the posts, then loop through them, ask the meta data and check if the expiration date falls between now `date(Y-m-d)` and three days `date(Y-M-d, mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+3, date("Y"))`